# How to add event handler for the text in pin mapview in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I am trying to use mapview features for first time. I have a mapview, textfield and search button. Currently everything works fine:

```
- (IBAction)searchLocation:(id)sender {
    // Create and initialize a search request object.
    MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = _nameLocation.text;
    request.region = _mapview.region;

    // Create and initialize a search object.
    MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    // Start the search and display the results as annotations on the map.
    [search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        NSMutableArray *placemarks = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems) {
            [placemarks addObject:item.placemark];
        }

        [_mapview removeAnnotations:[_mapview annotations]];
        [_mapview showAnnotations:placemarks animated:NO];

    }];
}
```

Now I need to add event handler to the pin. If the user click on the pin I want to open new controller and show the address as a text. I appreciate if anyone can show me how can I have a listener that when user click on the pin it does some function for me. In addition I want to have access to the address is showing on pin.

**EDIT**
I actually need to know when user click on the text showing by the pin. Here is "Miranda NSW" When user click on the text mean they accepted the address.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 2 delegate methods will let you know when the user select and deselect the pins

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

Add a disclosure button in your `viewForAnnotation` like this

```
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

Now when you tap on a pin on the mapView, a disclosure button will display in the presented view. You will then need to use the following method to tell the app what to do when the disclosure button is pressed.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

Comment: Thanks for that. And do you know how can I get the text in the pin?

Comment: I am not getting you properly.

Comment: Yes. Your code is called when I select the pin itself. But I need a listener when user click on the text showing by the pin. In above example is "Miranda NSW, Australia"

Comment: Now my only doubt is inside 'calloutAccessoryControlTapped' how can I access the text in the pin?